# Nilable value in appengine/datastore using Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

The list of supported types by datastore doesn't contain pointer types (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference).
How then can I represent a value that can and sometimes should be nil?
For example in the following structure I need the `DailyValuePercent` to be nilable to explicitly say that the value is missing.

```
type NutritionFact struct {
    Name                string  `datastore:",noindex" json:"name"`
    DailyValuePercent   int     `datastore:",noindex" json:"dailyValuePercent"`
}
```

Since I can't use *int as the field type for datastore then how to represent an optional value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either store your ints as strings (with empty string => no value) or use a composite type like:

```
type NillableInt struct {
    i     int
    isNil bool  // or isNotNil bool if you want different default semantics
}
```

Adapt to your performance vs. memory usage requirements.

If you want your code to deal with int pointers but persist nil values in the datastore, define your struct like this:

```
type NutritionFact struct {
       Name                string  `datastore:",noindex" json:"name"`
       DailyValuePercent   int `datastore:"-"`
}
```

And implement the PropertyLoadSaver interface where you will save/load an int value and a isNil boolean.

Comment: And I guess the third option would be to have *int in my struct and use PropertyLoadSaver to conditionally save it, right?
It's also worth noting that storing booleans (as I did) can use a lot of Datastore space wich may turn out to be expensive.